# How to replace only part of found text?

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have a file with a some comma separated names and some comma separated account numbers.
Names will always be something like `Dow, John` and numbers like `012394,19862`.

Using *Notepad++*'s "Regex Find" feature, I'd like to replace commas between numbers with pipes `|`.

Basically :

```
turn:  Dow,John      into:  Dow,John
       12345,09876          12345|09876
       13568,08642          13568|08642
```

I've been using `[0-9],` to *find* the commas, but I can't get it to properly leave the number's last digit and replace *just the comma*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question, because I had the exact same question but had no idea how to word it! 

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Search for `([0-9]),` and replace it with `\1|`. Does that work?

Comment: Ah, this seems to do it, thanks! I was trying `[0-9]` and replacing it with `\1|', which was NOT working, but adding the parenthesis as you did here works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Why do we need the parens?

Comment: @Patrick In regex, the parentheses create a capture group telling the parser to capture the parts within the group so that it can be used for replacements.

Comment: This also seems to work for TextPad.  Ex: Find ([0-9]),([a-z]) and replace \1|\2

Comment: Parenthesis is called "Grouped Backreference" in Regular Expression terminology.
()()() - in search
can be accessed in replace as \1 \2 \3 :)

Answer (score 15):

use this regex

```
(\d),(\d)
```

and replace it with

```
$1|$2
```

OR

```
\1|\2
```

Comment: @Blender that would make the same the same thing

Comment: This actually replaced "$1|$2" in-line into the text -- like it wasn't parsing $1 as anything but the intended string I wanted.

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It Ah, now that works. Thanks for this answer, though I've already marked the other as "the answer" since I used that one and had it working for me first.

Answer (score 3):

`(?<=\d),` should work. Oddly enough, this only works if I use replace all, but not if I use replace single. As an alternative, you can use `(\d),` and replace with `$1|`

Comment: I don't believe Notepad++ supports the `Lookahead` and `Lookbehind` assertions.

Comment: @Nick actually, it does. I have NP++ and this works (finds matches), but only replaces them if I use replace all. If I try to replace them case by case, it leaves them unchanged.

Comment: I believe you, I had only heard that. I haven't used NP++ for regex before.

Comment: I'm surprised there is a difference between Replace and Replace All - that's definitely worth remembering.

Answer (score 2):

**General thoughts about replacing only part of a match**

In order to replace a part of a match, you need to either 1) use capturing groups in the regex pattern and backreferences to the kept group values in the replacement pattern, or 2) lookarounds, or 3) a `\K` operator to discard left-hand context.

So, if you have a string like `a = 10`, and you want to replace the number after `a =` with, say, `500`, you can

- find `(a =)\d+` and replace with `\1500` / `${1}500` (if you use `$n` backreference syntax and it is followed with a digit, you should wrap it with braces)
- find `(?<=a =)\d+` and replace with `500` (since `(?<=...)` is a non-consuming positive lookbehind pattern and the text it matches is not added to the match value, and hence is not replaced)
- find `a =\K\d+` and replace with `500` (where `\K` makes the regex engine "forget" the text is has matched up to the `\K` position, making it similar to the lookbehind solution, but allowing any quantifiers, e.g. `a\h*=\K\d+` will match `a =` even if there are any zero or more horizontal whitespaces between `a` and `=`).

**Current problem solution**

In order to replace any comma in between two digits, you should use lookarounds:

**Find What**: `(?<=\d),(?=\d)`
**Replace With**: `|`

*Details*:

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the demo screenshot with settings:

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0orfZ/1).

*Variations*:

**Find What**: `(\d),(?=\d)`
**Replace With**: `\1|`

**Find What**: `\d\K,(?=\d)`
**Replace With**: `|`

Note: if there are comma-separated *single* digits, e.g. `1,2,3,4` you can't use `(\d),(\d)` since this will only match odd occurrences (see [what I mean](https://regex101.com/r/P0orfZ/2)).