# While replacing using regex, How to keep a part of matched string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have

```
12.hello.mp3
21.true.mp3
35.good.mp3
.
.
.
```

so on as file names in listed in a text file.

I need to replace only those dots(.) infront of numbers with a space.(e.g. 12.hello.mp3 => 12 hello.mp3). 
If I have regex as "[0-9].", it replaces number also.
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Notepad++ Regex to Find and Replace Only Part of Found Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164312/using-notepad-regex-to-find-and-replace-only-part-of-found-text)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Replace

```
^(\d+)\.(.*mp3)$
```

with

```
\1 \2
```

Also, in recent versions of notepad++, it will also accept the following, which is also accepted by other IDEs/editors (eg. JetBrains products like Intellij IDEA):

```
$1 $2
```

This assumes that the notepad++ regex matching engine supports groups. What the regex basically means is: match the digits in front of the first dot as group 1 and everything after it as group 2 (but only if it ends with *mp3*)

Comment: @Doug Yes, the groups are defined by the paratheses

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't even knew that this was possible with regex

Comment: Thanks. But to match all lines, it worked for me without using ^. Or it would only match first line. Tested on https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 4):

I tested with vscode. You must use groups with parentheses `(group of regex)`

##### Practical example

- start with sample data

```sh
1 a text
2 another text
3 yet more text
```

- Do the Regex to find/Search the numerical digits and spaces. The group here will be the digits as it is surrounded in parenthesis

```sh
(\d)\s
```

- Run a replace regex ops. Replace spaces for a dash but keep the numbers or digits in each line

```sh
$1-
```

- Outputs

```sh
1-a text
2-another text
3-yet more text
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here didn't make much sense to me and took me a while to figure things out.

---

Let's say I have this string:

- `return this.logSomething('text');`

and I want to turn it into this:

- `this.logSomething('text'); return;`

---

...then this is what the find field should contain:

- `return (this.logSomething\('[a-zA-Z0-9]*'\);)`

and this is what the replace field should contain:

- `$1 return;`

---

The insight here is the additional parentheses within the find field. They delimited your groups, which you then reference with `$1`, `$2`, and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

Using the basic pattern, well described in the accepted answer here is an example to add the `class="odd"` and `class="even"` to every `<tr>` element in *Notepad++* or any other regex compatible editor:

Find what: `(<tr><td>)(.*?\r\n)(<tr><td>)(.*?\r\n)`

Replace with: `<tr class="odd"><td>\2<tr class="even"><td>\4`