# Find/Replace characters next to numbers without replacing the actual number

Tags: regex, notepad++

I try to express myself as good as I can.

I am trying to find all "A" in a text with a "B" but only the ones that contain a number after it.

With the extended search I tried the following:

```
A[^A-Za-z]
```

This works, but this selects the number as well I do not want to replace the number. I only want to replace the character "A" to "B", while leaving the numbers as they are.

Is this somehow possible in Notepad++?

I greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While replacing using regex, How to keep a part of matched string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458160/while-replacing-using-regex-how-to-keep-a-part-of-matched-string)

Comment: Use `A([^A-Za-z])` => `B$1`. Or `A(?=\d)` => `B` if you really want to match `A`s that have a digit right after them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Find what: `A(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `B`

[image]

- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[image]