# notepad++ regex find, replace and KEEP the match

Tags: regex, notepad++

Ok, before I get the "already answered", I have found and tried every permutation I found at:

[While replacing using regex, How to keep a part of matched string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458160/while-replacing-using-regex-how-to-keep-a-part-of-matched-string)

[Using Notepad++ Regex to Find and Replace Only Part of Found Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164312/using-notepad-regex-to-find-and-replace-only-part-of-found-text)

I have these lines:

```
new MyObject("22222,11,21),
new MyObject("22223,12,22),
new MyObject("22224,13,23),
new MyObject("22225,14,24),
```

I'm trying to put the "end quote" around 22222, 22223, 22224 and 22225 for this:

```
new MyObject("22222",11,21),
new MyObject("22223",12,22),
new MyObject("22224",13,23),
new MyObject("22225",14,24),
```

The value I put into notepad++ for "Find What" is working (an escaped double quote plus 5 digits).

> \"\d{5}

for "replace with" (based on what I found at the previous two SOF articles), i have tried:

(these are just to test it)

```
aaa$1bbb
aaa$1$2bbb
aaa$1$2$3bbb
```

and

```
aaa\1bbb
aaa\1\2bbb
aaa\1\2\3bbb
```

Obviously, what I want (and what I think should work) is below (escaped double-quote, then the placeholder for "1", and the a second escaped double-quote)

```
\"\1\"\
```

or

```
\"$1\"\
```

My search mode is "regular express" and I've toggled ".matches newline" on and off.

> Notepad++ v7.7.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to capture the match in a capture group:

```
(\"\d{5})
```

The replace it with the captured value and a quote:

```
\1"
```

e.g.

[image]

Comment: #jackPot, I'll mark as answer as soon as it let's me.  Thanks.  I just replaced 33,000 lines in a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

No needs for capture group here, use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"\d{5}\K(?!")` or `(?<="\d{5})(?!")` (the former doesn't work in Npp when replacing one by one)
- Replace with: `"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           # a double quote
\d{5}       # 5 digits
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(?!")       # negative lookahead,make sure haven't double quote after
```

Or

```
"           # a double quote
(?<=        # positive lookbehind, make sure we have 5 digits before
    \d{5}       # 5 digits
)
(?!")       # negative lookahead,make sure haven't double quote after
```

**Result for given example:**

```
new MyObject("22222",11,21),
new MyObject("22223",12,22),
new MyObject("22224",13,23),
new MyObject("22225",14,24),
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: that is some magi"K" there.  << see what I did there

Comment: Why is this not working for a single *Replace*? Only *Replace all* works. Ingenious approach nonetheless!

Comment: @Prid: You're right, I don't know why but you can use `(?<="\d{5})` instead.

Comment: @Toto: Thanks, and great edit! I just think the previous revision was easier to understand for a n00b like me, while this new one -- although better and covering more options -- feels a bit "cluttered" and "scary" for new users  The way `\K` had all the attention made it super easy to understand for someone like me who hadn't ever seen it before and how it functioned. Now I'm getting scared off by that `(?!")` even though it's starting to make sense now. Just my 2 cents :)